# Solve $\ln(1+t) = t/(1+t)$

Tags: analysis, algebra-precalculus

How to solve
$$
 \ln(1+t) = \frac{t}{1+t}?
$$
By inspection I know that $t = 0$ is the only solution, but how to prove that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$
 g(t) = \ln(1+t) - \frac{t}{1+t} , \ \ t>-1
$$
$$
 g'(t)=\frac{t}{(1+t)^2}
$$

Thus $g(0)=0$ and $g$is increasing on $(0,\infty )$ and decreasing on $(-1 , 0)$, so there can be no other roots in $(-1 , \infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x = 1 + t \to t = x - 1$, and consider: $f(x) = xlnx - x + 1$ on $(0,\infty)$. We have:

$f'(x) = lnx + 1 - 1 + 0 = lnx > 0$ if $x > 1$, and $< 0$, if $0 < x < 1$. Thus if $x > 1$, $f(x) > f(1) = 0 \to g(x) = \dfrac{f(x)}{x} > 0$, and the equation has no solution. Similarly when $0 < x < 1$, $f(x) > f(1) = 0$, so $g(x) = \dfrac{f(x)}{x} > 0$, and the equation again has no solution. So $x = 1$, and $1 + t = 1 \to t = 0$ is the only solution.

Comment: But $\;\log(1+t)\;$ is defined **also** for $\;t>\color{red}{-1}\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

For $t\in\mathbb{R}$, the function $f(t)=\log(1+t)-\dfrac{t}{1+t}$ is increasing on $[0, \infty)$ and decreasing on $(-1, 0]$. The derivative is $f'(t)=\dfrac{t}{(1+t)^2}$.

- $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}f(t)=\infty$.
- $\lim\limits_{t\to-1^+}f(t)=\infty$.
- $f'(0) = 0$.
- $f(0) = 0$.

So, we have a proof that the only zero of $f(t)$ is when $t=0$. Have we?